# Regex: removing specific style attribute in HTML

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have a problem in regex.

I want to remove attribute style html backgroud-image in tag HTML, like this:

```
<span style="background-image:   url ("http://mantis.we.intern/custom/userfiles/image/6y0eC4vzptnIxsikHs0AJA.png"); bgcolor:'red'">11111<br />
<span style="background-image: url('https:// asd asdmantis.we.intern/custom/userfiles/image/6y0eC4vzptnIxsikHs0AJA.png')">22222
<span style="background-image:url('https://fmantis.we.intern/custom/userfiles/image/6y0eC4vzptnIxsikHs0AJA.png')">3333
<span style="background-image:url( 'https://fmantis.we.intern/custom/userfiles/image/6y0eC4vzptnIxsikHs0AJA.png')">444
<span style="background-image:   url ( "http://mantis.we.intern/custom/userfiles/image/6y0eC4vzptnIxsikHs0AJA.png");">555<br />
<span style="background-image: url(xx https://trk.workexpert.net/web/include/ckeditor_432/plugins/icons.png?t=E0LB& xx); >666
```

And the result from regex, could be like this:

```
<span style=" bgcolor:'red'">11111<br />
<span style="">22222
<span style="">3333
<span style="">444
<span style="">555<br />
<span style=" >666
```

Thank you, before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex does exactly what you need:

### `background-image:[^)]*[)];?`

It selects the words `background-image:` and then everything up until the first `)` with an optional `;`

[Regex101 Tested](https://regex101.com/r/dV3nN8/3)

Comment: Awesome! Please select this as the answer in that case :)